# Grounding in Prolog given a predicate and a list

Tags: prolog

Given a predicate and a list I want a list of all the possible ways of grounding. For example:

```
gounding(predicate(X), [a,b,c], Grounded).
```

Should return

```
[predicate(a), predicate(b), predicate(c)]
```

And I would also like it to work with more than one variable, for example:

```
grounding(predicate(X,Y), [a,b,c], Grounded).
Grounded = [predicate(a,a), predicate(a,b), predicate(a,c), predicate(b,a), predicate(b,b), predicate(b,c), predicate(c,a), predicate(c,b), predicate(c,c)]
```

The problem is given by the fact that **the predicate** is not always the same, so it **needs to be passed as a variable**. Like:

```
grounding(Predicate, Arity, [a,b,c], Grounded).
```

Is there something that already does this or should it be done manually?
I tried using *atom_concat* with the name of the predicate, the brackets and the elements of the list, but it returns the list with quotes like:

```
['predicate(a)', 'predicate(b)', 'predicate(c)']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's start with a simpler problem: Given a list of variables and a list of ground values, assign those ground values to the variables. For example:

```
?- variables_values([X], [a, b, c]).
X = a ;
X = b ;
X = c.
```

This can be implemented like this:

```
variables_values([], _Values).
variables_values([Variable | Variables], Values) :-
    member(Variable, Values),
    variables_values(Variables, Values).
```

A bigger example:

```
?- variables_values([X, Y], [a, b, c]).
X = Y, Y = a ;
X = a,
Y = b ;
X = a,
Y = c ;
X = b,
Y = a ;
X = Y, Y = b ;
X = b,
Y = c ;
X = c,
Y = a ;
X = c,
Y = b ;
X = Y, Y = c.
```

The `term_variables/2` predicate gives you a list of all the variables in a term. You can combine this with the above predicate:

```
?- Pattern = predicate(X, Y), term_variables(Pattern, Variables), variables_values(Variables, [a, b, c]).
Pattern = predicate(a, a),
X = Y, Y = a,
Variables = [a, a] ;
Pattern = predicate(a, b),
X = a,
Y = b,
Variables = [a, b] ;
Pattern = predicate(a, c),
X = a,
Y = c,
Variables = [a, c] ;
Pattern = predicate(b, a),
X = b,
Y = a,
Variables = [b, a] .  % etc.
```

Note that instantiating the variables in the list also instantiates them in the pattern -- the variables are shared.

Given this, the last piece of the puzzle is a predicate that computes a list of instantiations of a pattern, given some predicate that instantiates variables. `findall/3` is the right tool for this job:

```
pattern_values_grounded(Pattern, Values, Grounded) :-
    term_variables(Pattern, Variables),
    findall(Pattern, variables_values(Variables, Values), Grounded).
```

This does what you seem to want:

```
?- pattern_values_grounded(predicate(X), [a, b, c], Grounded).
Grounded = [predicate(a), predicate(b), predicate(c)].

?- pattern_values_grounded(predicate(X, Y), [a, b, c], Grounded).
Grounded = [predicate(a, a), predicate(a, b), predicate(a, c), predicate(b, a), predicate(b, b), predicate(b, c), predicate(c, a), predicate(c, b), predicate(..., ...)].
```